# ¿Cómo cancelar la selección en un UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

En el coding the de abajo comprueba si la condición es `true`, enseña una marca de verificación en el `cell`si no, enseña nada. ¿Como puedo hacer que el usuario pueda deseleccionar el `cell` pulsando en el dispositivo?

```
// Boolean Array 
var esVisitado = [Bool] (count: 21, repeatedValues: false)
if Visitado[indexPath.row] {
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
return cell


let esVisitadoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Que quieres decir?", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    self.Visitado[indexPath.row] = true

})

optionMenu.addAction(esVisitadoAction)

tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de una hora tratando de arreglar este problema al fin pude resolver mi problema, lo que tenia que era:

```
let esVisitadoTitulo = (esVisitado[indexPath.row]) ? "Seleccionar" : "deseleccionar"
let esVisitadoAction = UIAlertAction(title: esVisitadoTitulo, style: .Default, handler: {

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            self.Visitado[indexPath.row] = (self.Visitado[indexPath.row]) ? false : true;
            cell?.accessoryType = (self.Visitado[indexPath.row]) ? .Checkmark : .None
```

Ahora cuando seleccionas algo te pregunta `Seleccionar` y si quieres `deseleccionar` tienes que tocar otra vez y seleccionar `Deseleccionar`. Todavía no e podido encontrar una manera para poder deseleccionar, cuando el usuario pulse en el dispositivo 2 veces.

Comment: En primer lugar, procura no crear otra respuesta cada vez que consigas algo con tu problema, sino modificar la pregunta que ya has hecho y luego añadir el nuevo código señalándolo con un texto como "Editado". Segundo, cual es la estructura del array `self.Visitado`?, nos podrías mostrar el contenido?. Ten en cuenta que `indexPath.row` te devuelve indexes como `0, 1, 2,...`, por lo tanto el comportamiento de tu código será impredecible.

Comment: yo use un Boolean array, en vez de repetir `false` 21 veces o cuantas veces el programa tenga que usar el array. Mira al array lo edite en mi código @ThXou

Comment: Yo creo que el código esta un poco confuso porque los nombres que le di a las variables en el código original esta en otro idioma y lo tuve que acomodar para que puedan entrenar, dime si entiendes el codigo si no puedo subir el código original. @ThXou

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te pongo el modo en que podrías hacerlo llevando a cabo mejores prácticas como la creación de un modelo para los datos que pones en el `TableView`:

```
import UIKit

class MyObject {
    var title = ""
    var selected = false

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var visitados = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let object1 = MyObject.init(title: "Título 1")
        let object2 = MyObject.init(title: "Título 2")
        let object3 = MyObject.init(title: "Título 3")

        visitados = [object1, object2, object3]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return visitados.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let object = visitados[indexPath.row] as! MyObject
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = object.title
        cell.accessoryType = (object.selected) ? .Checkmark : .None

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let object = visitados[indexPath.row] as! MyObject
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        if object.selected {
            cell!.accessoryType = .None
            object.selected = false
        }
        else {
            cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            object.selected = true
        }

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

En este caso `MyObject` representaría a cada dato que quieras poner en el `TableView`. Solo he definido un título y su estado, para saber si está o no seleccionado. Es completamente funcional.

El hecho de hacerlo modular te permite organizar mejor tu código y hacerlo más legible. Siempre que sea posible utiliza este tipo de patrón a la hora de crear tus aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes el codigo para un tap y dos tap. Lo que tienes que hacer es decirle cuatas veces es necesario que pulse con `numberOfTapsRequired`

```
let t2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"PulsacionDoble")
        t2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        self.v.addGestureRecognizer(t2)

        let t1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"PulsacionSimple")
        t1.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(t2)
        self.v.addGestureRecognizer(t1)

         func PulsacionDoble() {
        print("Pulsacion Simple")
    }
    func PulsacionSimple() {
        print("Pulsacion Doble")
    }
```